# How to tell when window.print() completes on Android

Tags: javascript, android, printing

I'm building a web site for our charity which needs to print labels.  The page has 2 primary divs which overlay one another.  One div contains a form and the other contains the label which needs to be printed.  When the user presses the print button on the form, the form's div is set style is set to display:none and the other div is set to display:block.  I then call window.print()

The issue is that window.print is asynchronous, so I have no idea when it completes.  As a result, the javascript waits for 15 seconds before switching back to the form window.  That works OK most of the time, but sometimes I get a screenshot of the form if the user takes too long to click on the window.print's print button.

I've also tried window.onafterprint, but that event occurs immediately on Chrome/Android.

Is there someway to reliably print the div containing the label (i.e. to know when the print.window process has completed)?  Note that this web site will only be used on Android based tablets that the charity uses, so that at least constrains the issues.

Comment: call window.onafterprint() not window.print()

Comment: I am calling window.onafterprint, but on Android I get the form printed, not the label.  On Windows it works properly.  Here's the code:
    window.onafterprint= function() {
        document.getElementById("label").style.display="none";
        document.getElementById("wrapper").style.display="block";
    }
    window.print();

Answer (score 0):

You could just add a console output at the end so you see when it is finished